# table-column-width from siunitx varies depending on the content

Tags: tables, siunitx

I was trying to have a table with 3 column which become 2.

While I was testing some options, I noticed that `table-column-width` option of `siunitx` doesn't produce the same width, depending of what the content is.

Why?

Compare the dimensions of two sub-tabulars, one over another, in the following two tables (see what highlighted in the red rectangles).

(Every suggestion to improve the table is welcome. The vertical rules in the example are only there for showing the problem.)

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{tmargin=3cm,bmargin=3.5cm,lmargin=4cm,rmargin=3cm,
    marginparwidth=70pt}

\usepackage{array}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{makecell}
\newcommand{\tabitem}{--~~}%{~~\llap{--}~~} % command for itemizing in tables
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf,labelsep=period,format=hang]{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{position=above, aboveskip=2pt}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\newlength{\mylen}
\setlength{\mylen}{2.5em}
\newcolumntype{A}[1]{S[table-format =#1]}
\newcolumntype{B}[2]{S[table-format =#1,table-column-width =#2]}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\newcommand{\baselii}{\mbox{Basel~II}} 

\usepackage{environ}
\newcommand{\tabfs}{\small}
\NewEnviron{tabnote}[1][para]{%
    \begin{tablenotes}[#1]    
        \footnotesize \BODY
    \end{tablenotes} 
}
\NewEnviron{tabella}{%
    \begin{table}[!tbh]
        \centering\tabfs
        \begin{threeparttable}
            \BODY
        \end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}
}

\raggedbottom

\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabella}
        \caption{Weights in the Standardized Approach of \baselii\label{tab:withB}}
        \begin{tabular}{l*2{A{2}}*3{B{3}{\mylen}}*2{A{3}}}
            \toprule 
            Category of claims & \multicolumn{6}{c}{Weights (\%) depending on
                ratings\tnote{a}}\\
            \cmidrule{2-7} 
             & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\makecell{AAA \\to AA$-$}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\makecell{A$+$ \\to A$-$}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\makecell{BBB$+$ \\to BBB$-$}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\makecell{BB$+$ \\to B$-$}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\makecell{Below \\B$-$}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Unrated}\\
            \midrule
            Sovereigns & 0 & 20 & 50 & 100 & 150 & 100\\\midrule%[1ex] 
            Non-central government PSEs: & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}\\
            \tabitem option 1 & 20 & 50 & 100 & 100 & 150 & 100\\
            \tabitem option 2 & 20 & 50 & 50 & 100 & 150 & 50\\\midrule%[1ex] 
            MDBs & 20 & 50 & 50 & 100 & 150 & 50\\\midrule%[1ex] 
            Banks: & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\
            \tabitem option 1 & 20 & 50 & 100 & 100 & 150 & 100\\
            \tabitem option 2 & 20 & 50 & 50 & 100 & 150 & 50\\
            \tabitem option 2 - short-term claims & 20 & 20 & 20 & 50 & 150 & 20\\
            \midrule 
             & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\makecell{AAA \\to AA$-$}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\makecell{A$+$ \\to A$-$}} &
             \multicolumn{3}{@{}c@{}}{\begin{tabular}{@{\hspace{1.34\tabcolsep}}*2{B{3}{1.5\mylen+.33\tabcolsep}}}
                    \multicolumn{1}{|B{3}{1.5\mylen+.33\tabcolsep}|}{\makecell{BBB$+$ \\to BB$-$}} &  
                     \multicolumn{1}{B{3}{1.5\mylen+.33\tabcolsep}|}{\makecell{Below \\BB$-$}}\\ 
                \end{tabular}}
                         & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Unrated} \\
            \cmidrule{2-7}
            Corporate & 20 & 50 & \multicolumn{3}{@{}c@{}}{\begin{tabular}{|@{\hspace{1.34\tabcolsep}}*2{B{3}{1.5\mylen+.33\tabcolsep}|}} 100 & 150\\\end{tabular}} & 100\\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
        \begin{tabnote}
            \item[a]{The vertical rules are only for illustrative purpose.}
        \end{tabnote}
    \end{tabella}
The sub-\verb|tabular|s in Table \ref{tab:withB} are built with the \verb|table-column-width| option of \verb|siunitx|: why does the with 
of the \verb|tabular| with the headers differ from the one with the numbers?  

With an ordinary \verb|p{...}| it doesn't happen, compare Table \ref{tab:withC}.
    \begin{tabella}
        \caption{Weights in the Standardized Approach of \baselii\label{tab:withC}}
        \begin{tabular}{l*2{A{2}}*3{B{3}{\mylen}}*2{A{3}}}
            \toprule 
            Category of claims & \multicolumn{6}{c}{Weights (\%) depending on
                ratings\tnote{a}}\\
            \cmidrule{2-7} 
             & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\makecell{AAA \\to AA$-$}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\makecell{A$+$ \\to A$-$}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\makecell{BBB$+$ \\to BBB$-$}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\makecell{BB$+$ \\to B$-$}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\makecell{Below \\B$-$}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Unrated}\\
            \midrule
            Sovereigns & 0 & 20 & 50 & 100 & 150 & 100\\\midrule%[1ex] 
            Non-central government PSEs: & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}\\
            \tabitem option 1 & 20 & 50 & 100 & 100 & 150 & 100\\
            \tabitem option 2 & 20 & 50 & 50 & 100 & 150 & 50\\\midrule%[1ex] 
            MDBs & 20 & 50 & 50 & 100 & 150 & 50\\\midrule%[1ex] 
            Banks: & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\
            \tabitem option 1 & 20 & 50 & 100 & 100 & 150 & 100\\
            \tabitem option 2 & 20 & 50 & 50 & 100 & 150 & 50\\
            \tabitem option 2 - short-term claims & 20 & 20 & 20 & 50 & 150 & 20\\
            \midrule 
            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\makecell{AAA \\to AA$-$}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\makecell{A$+$ \\to A$-$}} &
            \multicolumn{3}{@{}c@{}}{\begin{tabular}{|@{\hspace{1.34\tabcolsep}}*2{C{1.5\mylen}@{\hspace{1.33\tabcolsep}}|}}
                    \makecell{BBB$+$ \\to BB$-$} &  
                    \makecell{Below \\BB$-$}\\ 
            \end{tabular}}
            & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Unrated} \\
            \cmidrule{2-7}
            Corporate & 20 & 50 & \multicolumn{3}{@{}c@{}}{\begin{tabular}{|@{\hspace{1.34\tabcolsep}}*2{C{1.5\mylen}@{\hspace{1.33\tabcolsep}}|}} 100 & 150\\\end{tabular}} & 100\\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
        \begin{tabnote}
            \item[a]{The vertical rules are only for illustrative purpose.}
        \end{tabnote}
    \end{tabella}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\mylen` seems to be smaller than natural width of columns, which are accommodated to widths of their headers (`to BBB -`). try to increase it.

Comment: i didn't deeply study/test your code in question yet. but from question title, i conclude that problem is in the defined width of columns.

Comment: any news? you receive two answers ...

Comment: ok, than enjoy as much as it is possible :-).

Comment: it was clear to me from beginning (i think so). i believe that your problem is described in my comments and Ulrike answer and solved by my answer. see my edited answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i suppose that you like obtain something like this:

[image]

i consider only the first table. difference between proposed solution an your table are:

- increased size of `\mylen` (see my comment below question)
- removed are all `\multicolumn{1}{c}{...}` which override your basic column definition, i.e.: determination of the `table-column-width` with natural width of its content
- in `\multicolumn{3}{c}{...}`, which is used for nested table, `\tabcolsep` is left out by `@{}` at their beginnings and ends.
- recalculated column width in nested tables (now is equal to width of the spanned columns)

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{tmargin=3cm,bmargin=3.5cm,lmargin=4cm,rmargin=3cm,
    marginparwidth=70pt}

\usepackage{array}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{makecell}
\newcommand{\tabitem}{--~~}%{~~\llap{--}~~} % command for itemizing in tables
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf,labelsep=period,format=hang]{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{position=above, aboveskip=2pt}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\newlength{\mylen}
\setlength{\mylen}{4em} % <--- increased
\newcolumntype{A}[1]{S[table-format =#1]}
\newcolumntype{B}[2]{S[table-format =#1,table-column-width =#2]}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\newcommand{\baselii}{\mbox{Basel~II}}

\usepackage{environ}
\newcommand{\tabfs}{\small}
\NewEnviron{tabnote}[1][para]{%
    \begin{tablenotes}[#1]
        \footnotesize \BODY
    \end{tablenotes}
}
\NewEnviron{tabella}{%
    \begin{table}[!tbh]
        \centering\tabfs
        \begin{threeparttable}
            \BODY
        \end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}
}

\raggedbottom
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabella}
        \caption{Weights in the Standardized Approach of \baselii\label{tab:withB}}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
\begin{tabular}{l*2{A{2}}|*3{B{3}{\mylen}|}*2{A{3}}}
    \toprule
    Category of claims & \multicolumn{6}{c}{Weights (\%) depending on
        ratings\tnote{a}}\\
    \cmidrule{2-7}
& {\makecell{AAA \\to AA$-$}}   & {\makecell{A$+$ \\to A$-$}} & {\makecell{BBB$+$ \\to BBB$-$}}
& {\makecell{BB$+$ \\to B$-$}}  & {\makecell{Below \\B$-$}}   & {Unrated}\\
    \midrule
    Sovereigns & 0 & 20 & 50 & 100 & 150 & 100\\\midrule%[1ex]
    Non-central government PSEs: & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}\\
    \tabitem option 1 & 20 & 50 & 100 & 100 & 150 & 100\\
    \tabitem option 2 & 20 & 50 & 50 & 100 & 150 & 50\\\midrule%[1ex]
    MDBs & 20 & 50 & 50 & 100 & 150 & 50\\\midrule%[1ex]
    Banks: & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\
    \tabitem option 1 & 20 & 50 & 100 & 100 & 150 & 100\\
    \tabitem option 2 & 20 & 50 & 50 & 100 & 150 & 50\\
    \tabitem option 2 - short-term claims & 20 & 20 & 20 & 50 & 150 & 20\\
    \midrule
    & {\makecell{AAA \\to AA$-$}} & {\makecell{A$+$ \\to A$-$}}
                        & \multicolumn{3}{@{} c @{}}{  % <---
                          \begin{tabular}{@{}|*2{B{3}{1.5\mylen+\tabcolsep+3\arrayrulewidth}|}  % <---
                                          @{}}
                          {\makecell{BBB$+$ \\to BB$-$}}
                                & {\makecell{Below \\BB$-$}}
                        \end{tabular}}      & {Unrated} \\
    \cmidrule{2-7}
    Corporate & 20 & 50 & \multicolumn{3}{@{} c @{}}{  % <---
                          \begin{tabular}{@{}|*2{B{3}{1.5\mylen+\tabcolsep+3\arrayrulewidth}|}  % <---
                                          @{}}
                          100   & 150
                          \end{tabular}}    & 100   \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabnote}
    \item[a]{The vertical rules are only for illustrative purpose.}
\end{tabnote}
\end{tabella}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that I understand the question. But to simplify the problem:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|S[table-column-width=1cm]|} 
abc
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}{|S[table-column-width=1cm]|}
\multicolumn{1}{l}{XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX}\\
abc
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{|p{1cm}|}
abc
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}{|p{1cm}|}
\multicolumn{1}{l}{XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX}\\
abc
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

This shows that \multicolumn overrides the width of `table-column-width`. So your example should at first get rid of all \multicolumn to avoid that they interfere.

Comment: I'm still not seeing what the _problem_ is: that all looks OK to me!

Comment: @JosephWright to me too. (I added a few remarks for clarification and will delete the answer when carla's question is clearer)

Comment: (To be clear: the header is too wide for the column, so the behaviour as far as `siunitx` is concerned is undefined, though from implementation details I'd anticipate what is seen.)

Comment: @JosephWright Please look at the Corporate headers w.r.t. the row with the numbers. Probably Ulrike got the problem but I can't test it at the moment